# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Instead, the actual type was: 'Promise' React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a client-side problem. The server side is working fine, and the `deleteCourse` method deletes the course, but I get the error you see in the title on the client side. I am not sure what is going on. If I need to provide something else, just ask :D

/actions/courses.js

```js
export const deleteCourse = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    await api.deleteCourse(id);
    dispatch({ type: DELETE, payload: id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

```
/reducers/courses.js
```

```
import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE } from '../../constants/actionTypes';
export default (courses = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ALL:
      return action.payload;
    case CREATE:
      return [...courses, action.payload];
    case UPDATE:
      return courses.map((course) =>
        course._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : course
      );
    case DELETE:
      return courses.filter((course) => course._id !== action.payload);
    default:
      return courses;
  }
};
```

```
/api/index.js
```

```
import axios from 'axios';
//Our route
const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000' });
//Occurse before all the bellow requests
//Za google je result a za klasican je token
API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('profile'))
    req.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')).token
    }`;

  return req;
});
export const signIn = (formData) => API.post('/user/signIn', formData);
export const signUp = (formData) => API.post('/user/signUp', formData);
export const fetchCourses = () => API.get('/courses');
export const createCourse = (newCourse) => API.post('/courses', newCourse);
export const updateCourse = (id, updatedCourse) =>
  API.patch(`./courses/${id}`, updatedCourse);
export const deleteCourse = (id) => API.delete(`./courses/${id}`);
```

```
/index.js
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../src/api/reducers';
const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

/Button that starts the action

```
<Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {
          dispatch(deleteCourse(course._id))}}><DeleteIcon fontSize="small" /> Delete</Button>
```

I tried to console.log deleteCourse and I see that it is a resolved promise. Now I am watching some courses on youtube, and making my own project, but all of this is working for that guy just perfectly.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Dispatched actions should be objects like :

```
{ type: DELETE, payload: id }
```

but you are dispatching a function here :

```
 dispatch(deleteCourse(course._id))
```

Instead of dispatching a function I think you should just call it. Internally your function is dispatching the action you want so you should be good.

```
<Button size="small" color="primary" onClick={() => {
          deleteCourse(course._id)}}><DeleteIcon fontSize="small" /> Delete</Button>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It doesn't fire the action like that. Funny thing is that i have other calls like one i mentioned that work just fine like
const handleSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(createCourse({...courseData, hostName: user.userObject !== undefined ?   user.userObject.name 
            : user.result.name}));
    closeForm(!closeForm);
  }

Comment: Can there be some problem with thunk Middleware, maybe i should update projet to redux tools, as it is newer way of doing redux?

Answer (score 0):

Generally: you did not configure the `redux-thunk` middleware, and without that it won't work.

Edit: no, you did - at that point I'm honestly not 100% sure why you are getting that error message then.

---

But apart from that: you are writing a style of Redux here that is outdated over three years at this point and probably 4 times the amount of code, with more indirection and harder to learn.
You should not write code like this in 2022.

Please read [why Redux Toolkit is how to use Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and then follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) that will teach you RTK from the start.

Comment: Thank you, i will try to implement Redux toolkit and find out if it will work then. I figured that there is no direct problem in my code.